# Restangular application

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have an `angularJs` application with `restAngularJS`. Application is working fine on Desktop browsers.
When I am trying same on Ipad (chrome / safari / firefox) application is not working. I am getting 304 code on apache log. 
Any Idea where to hit to solve this problem... any approach.

From mobile device or ipad I am not getting HIT on my PHP rest url e.g. /api/students/ . But from desktop this was not a case. any clue?

Comment: code 304 means that the content has been cached in browser and hasn't been change d since.
So it's basically not an error condition. 
If you want to prevent your browser from caching server responses just configure restAngular resource to not use cache.

Comment: From mobile device or ipad I am not getting HIT on my PHP rest url e.g. /api/students/ . But from desktop this was not a case. any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 304 does not mean error, it means that your data has been cached. So, could be a layout issue for this data, or a bunch of possibilities.

Comment: From mobile device or ipad I am not getting HIT on my PHP rest url e.g. /api/students/ . But from desktop this was not a case. any clue?

Comment: but you were saying that you got a 304 code on yours logs, so basically, the HIT was successful. Just a thought, maybe in your ipad or mobile doesn't display that much due to layout issues, but this is just an opinion